# How to generate an histogram using iOS GPUImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gpuimage

Working on https://github.com/luisespinoza/LEColorPicker project, I am trying to generate an histogram UIImage from an arbitrary input UIImage using the project GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

The current code that I'm using is the following:

```
- (NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithColorsPickedFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    GPUImageFilter *filter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc] initWithHistogramType:kGPUImageHistogramRGB];

    UIImage *filteredImage = [filter imageByFilteringImage:image];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(filteredImage) writeToFile:@"/Users/Luis/histogram.png" atomically:YES];

    return nil;
}
```

The problem is that histogram.png is resulting in just a black line for every input image.

So, how will be the correct code to generate an histogram UIImage using iOS GPUImage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the FilterShowcase example to see how this is supposed to work in practice.

The GPUImageHistogramFilter takes in an image and outputs a 256x3 image that encodes the histogram (it's 3 pixels tall because a 1 pixel height isn't allowed in framebuffer construction). The R, G, and B values are stored in their respective color channels within a central 1-pixel-tall stripe at the center of that image.

To visualize this, you'll need to use a GPUImageHistogramGenerator, and feed the GPUImageHistogramFilter's output into that. The GPUImageHistogramGenerator creates a visual representation of the histogram input as an image. You do need to use `-forceProcessingAtSize:` to set the size for the GPUImageHistogramGenerator's output image, because it doesn't have a set size by default.

One other caution is that you'll need to have a dummy filter of some kind between your input image and the GPUImageHistogramFilter. GPUImageHistogramFilter currently relies on `glReadPixels()` and that only works for rendered content, not directly uploaded images or video frames.

The code used in the FilterShowcase for this is as follows:

```
        filter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc] initWithHistogramType:kGPUImageHistogramRGB];

        GPUImageGammaFilter *gammaFilter = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];
        [videoCamera addTarget:gammaFilter];
        [gammaFilter addTarget:filter];

        GPUImageHistogramGenerator *histogramGraph = [[GPUImageHistogramGenerator alloc] init];

        [histogramGraph forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(256.0, 330.0)];
        [filter addTarget:histogramGraph];

        GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
        blendFilter.mix = 0.75;            
        [blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(256.0, 330.0)];

        [videoCamera addTarget:blendFilter];
        [histogramGraph addTarget:blendFilter];

        [blendFilter addTarget:filterView];
```

This overlays the generated histogram visualization on top of the incoming camera video.

Comment: how to apply it on UIImage or GPUImage as overlay

Comment: Why is there Gamma filter in between?

Comment: @DeepakSharma - Due to the need for a dummy filter for camera data so that glReadPixels() will pull values. It's a hack, and at some point I intended to fix this more permanently, but haven't gotten around to it.