# GPUImageHistogramFilter for a still image giving zero data

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

Very similar this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391997/how-to-generate-an-histogram-using-ios-gpuimage), except I want to generate a histogram for a still image.

Below is what I'm doing, and it's giving a histogram with all 0 data. Is there some trick to getting this working?

```
GPUImageFilter *filter = [[GPUImageHistogramFilter alloc]  initWithHistogramType:kGPUImageHistogramRGB];

GPUImagePicture *original = [[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

GPUImageGammaFilter *gammaFilter = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];
[original addTarget:gammaFilter];
[gammaFilter addTarget:filter];

GPUImageHistogramGenerator *histogramGraph = [[GPUImageHistogramGenerator alloc] init];

[histogramGraph forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(256.0, 330.0)];
[filter addTarget:histogramGraph];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
blendFilter.mix = 0.75;
[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(256.0, 330.0)];

[original addTarget:blendFilter];
[histogramGraph addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter addTarget:gpuImageView];

[original processImage];
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're autoreleasing the ```GPUImagePicture  *original``` object? It's possible it's getting deallocated at the end of the method.

Comment: @AndrewTheis I think GPUImage is a non-ARC library

Comment: @aug2uag GPUImage is ARC compatible

Answer (score 0):

Brad has changed some inner mechanism to GPUImage to improve memory management (and it does)in the last releases, now you should tell  the filter to keep the frame for still images `-useNextFrameForImageCapture` .

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lambeau.jpg"];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageSepiaFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
[stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture]
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```